# How to make stair with grasses

Tags: landscaping, gardening, lawn

I found this picture online and wonder what material being used as the retaining wall for the grasses?

[image]

It looks like a long piece of metal horizontally. But it could also be pressure treated lumber.

How to even prevent this from moving or falling over after many years? Is this a good idea for maintenance purpose?

I am sure it looks beautiful.

Comment: If I did that, it would be stairs of weeds.  :-)  Are you sure that isn't Astroturf?

Comment: My guess is AstroTurf, imagine mowing!

Comment: Since grass doesn't much care where it grows, you're essentially asking what to use for a retaining wall. That question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe its turf and not real grass. You have also asked how to prevent this from moving or falling off. So in case it is real grass ; grasses Belo to the category "runners" (it is one category among the sub aerial modifications of stem). Runners don't have the ability to cross obstacles. So the edge of the stair is its boundary and it will not fall off. However if it grows long it will require mowing or cutting with a scissor.

Comment: Using Tineye reverse image search, the earliest form of this image dates back to 2015 at a site that is now defunct, but the original image was on a page named "artificialgrass.html", so that's fairly definitive.